# CriticalSection access violation Из-за чего ошибка?

Tags: delphi, потоки-данных

Доброго дня, есть Frame там создаются потоки с CS. Создаю CS я при открытии формы вот так:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Frame21.CS := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;
```

Вот код Frame:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.Samples.Spin, SyncObjs;

type
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    CS: TCriticalSection;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  Parser = class(TThread)
  private

  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
  end;

var
  Frame: TFrame2;
  CountAcc: integer;
  Work: boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor Parser.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

procedure Parser.Execute;
begin
  while Work do
  begin
    try
      CS.Enter;
      Inc(CountAcc);
      //Прочий код

      CS.Leave;
      // Прочий код
    except On E:Exception do begin

    showmessage(e.Message);
      sleep(1000);
    end;
    end;
  end;
end;
end.
```

В итоге я получаю ошибку: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш код не должен скомпилироваться. CS не видна внутри класса Parser. Чтоб критическая секция была доступна из потока ее нужно в него передать:

```
Parser = class(TThread)
private
  FLock: TCriticalSection;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
public
  constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ALock: TCriticalSection);
end;

constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ALock: TCriticalSection);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FLock:=ALock;
end;

procedure Execute;
begin
  FLock.Enter;
  try
    //Изменение глобальных данных
    Inc(CountAcc);
  finally
    FLock.Leave;
  end;
end;
```

По поводу переменной work. Она не нужна. у TThred есть свойство Terminated:Boolean пользуйтесь им. Т.е. из формы вы хотите остановить поток или все потоки, вызовите у них `p.Terminate`; и цикл внутри Execute у вас должен быть `while not Terminated do...`

По поводу фреймов не понял что там откуда должно быть доступно. Уточните.

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись и помогли. Насчет доступности мне нужно сделать так что бы созданные переменные во Frame были глобальны в самом фрейме и были доступны в главной форме аля: Frame1.peremennay

Comment: И что бы все функции, процедуры созданные во фрейме были так же доступны Frame1.funcname а не funcname

Comment: @infolabs свойства вашего фрейма будут доступны из фрейма. а чтоб они были доступны из главной форме, они должны быть в секции public фрейма. вот если вам надо иметь доступ из потока, то вы также как и критическую секцию можете передать в поток и ссылку на фрейм. только выполняя действия со свойствами и методами фрейма из потока не забудьте что это надо делать в синхронном методе:

    procedure Parser.Execute;
    begin
      ...
      Synchronize(ChangeFrameMethod);
      ...
    end;
    procedure ChangeFrameMethod;
    begin
      FFrame.SetLabel('я из парсера');
    end;

Comment: посмотрите в демках threads, там показано как обращаться к методам и свойствам к форме из потока.

Comment: Parser = class(TThread)
  private
    Frame: TFrame2;
//....
end;


procedure Parser.Sync;
begin
  showmessage('test');
  Frame.Label12.Caption := 'test';

Выдает вот эту ошибку http://joxi.ru/uploads/prod/20130901/1de/21b/d0f1a5d06969d006fdead4d2dbca32a9273c93a5.png?v=2.3.6

Comment: а через конструктор заполняете Frame?

    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ALock: TCriticalSection; AFrame: TFrame1);
    begin
      inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
      FLock:=ALock;
      Frame:=AFrame;
    end;

и тогда к Frame можно будет обращаться в синхронной функции.

Comment: Прописал в
Parser = class(TThread)
  private
    CS: TCriticalSection;
    CFrame: TFrame1;
//...
public
    procedure Sync;
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; Lock: TCriticalSection; IFrame: TFrame1);
end;
//...
constructor Parser.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; Lock: TCriticalSection; IFrame: TFrame1);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  CS := Lock;
  CFrame := IFrame;
end;
//...
var
Frame: TFrame1;
begin
Parser.Create(false, CS, Frame);
//...

Comment: не совсем понял где вы создаете поток. вот набросал [gist](https://gist.github.com/ivanovsuper/6417319).

Answer (score 2):

Для начала создай 
`CS:=TСriticalSection.Create;`

Работать лучше так

```
 `CS.Enter;
 try
   // что-то делаем...
   finally
  CS.Leave;
 end;`
```

Comment: Так я же создал! Смотрите:
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Frame21.CS := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

Answer (score 1):

Крит. секция создается там же, где она используется. Если исп. в потоке, то там же и должна создаваться. 
Если нужно в Execute, то там же(НЕ в TThread) создаёте крит. секцию там же её используете.
Только метод Execute исполняется внутри доп. созданного потока, сам TThread живет в основном потоке.

Comment: Да только как это реализовать правильно, что бы при закрытии программы все эти переменные уничтожались?

Comment: И как в таком случае сделать что бы переменные созданные в Frames (В Unit var ...)
Были доступны только в этом фрейме?

Comment: Объявить их в объявлении класса фрейма.

Comment: критическая секция предотвращает вход из другого места в нее. т.е. войдя в одном потоке в критическую секцию, из другого потока войти в нее нельзя, один поток будет ждать, когда другой поток из нее выйдет. и сама по себе критическая секция созданная в одном месте и используемая только там смысла не имеет.

Comment: если доступ к переменной `a` нужно ограничить один поток в один момент времени может писать (и возможно читать) в данную переменную, то критическая секция должна быть одна и доступна из всех таких потоков. и каждое обращение к переменной `a` должно быть заключено в enter-leave. только тогда она будет thread-safe.